# Creating a 2D color gradient based on RGB values in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to create a simple 2D square figure containing 2 color gradients based on RGB values, such that:

```
1) the bottom left corner of the square (0, 0) is green [0, 255, 0]
2) the bottom right corner of the square (255, 0) is red [255, 0, 0]
3) the top left corner of the square (0, 255) is blue [0, 0, 255]
4) the top right corner of the square (255, 255) is purple [255, 0, 255]
```

I think there should be a quick and easy way to do this with numpy and matplotlib, but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In numpy, we can use `np.linspace()` in 2D to calculate the red, green, and blue channels:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def arr_creat(upperleft, upperright, lowerleft, lowerright):
    arr = np.linspace(np.linspace(lowerleft, lowerright, arrwidth), 
                      np.linspace(upperleft, upperright, arrwidth), arrheight, dtype=int)
    return arr[:, :, None]

arrwidth = 256
arrheight = 256

r = arr_creat(0,   255, 0,   255)
g = arr_creat(0,   0,   255, 0)
b = arr_creat(255, 255, 0,   0)

img = np.concatenate([r, g, b], axis=2)

plt.imshow(img, origin="lower")
plt.axis("off")

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: This also works, interesting that our gradients look slightly different...

Comment: Your green channel does not blend properly. The value is constant up to i=j and only then decreases gradually. Hence, you have this flipping line from one state to the other for i=j and a square appearance of the color quadrants.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out without numpy, this is what I was looking for (in case anybody is interested):

```
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xlist = []
ylist = []
colorlist = []

for i in range(0, 256):
    for j in range(0, 256):
        xlist.append(i)
        ylist.append(j)
        if i > j:
            colorlist.append(((float(i/255), float((255-i)/255), float(j/255))))
        else:
            colorlist.append(((float(i/255), float((255-j)/255), float(j/255))))

fig = plt.scatter(xlist, ylist, c=colorlist, edgecolor='none', marker='s')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

import numpy as np

from numpy.random import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = random((3,2))
print(T.shape)

plt.imshow(T)

Output:

[Returns random RGB colors]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRXy4.png